# how to create gitlab pipeline to integrate and execute multiple powershell scripts

Tags: azure, powershell, gitlab, gitlab-ci

To perform azure migration, we have a batch of scripts available written in powershell.

**Plan:** We have to write .gitlab-ci.yml Gitlab pipeline to automate entire azure migration. To authenticate Azure when creating a GitLab pipeline, we will be using Azure Service Principal. This is a service account that will be used to authenticate and authorize GitLab to access Azure resources. So, we will be adding following variables in CI/CD settings as well:

- **AZURE_CLIENT_ID:** the client ID of the Service Principal
- **AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET:** the client secret of the Service Principal
- **AZURE_TENANT_ID:** the tenant ID of the Service Principal

How to create robust Gitlab pipeline to automate this entire azure migration?

Answer (score 0):

I have added my .gitlab-ci.yml and Powershell script with service Principal authentication like below :-

[image]

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```yaml
    scriptjob:
     stage:  build
     image: 
     name:  "mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:latest"
     script:
     -  pwsh  ./myscript.ps1
```

***[mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:latest](http://mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:latest)  - Is the image used to run Powershell scripts on gitlab.***

**Powershell script :-**

```
Install-Module  -Name Az -AllowClobber -Force`
$AppId="<App-Id>"
$AppSecret="<App-secret>"
# We need to convert the password to a secure string
$SecureSecret = $AppSecret | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
# We then create a new object to encapsulate the Application ID and secret
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
-ArgumentList $AppId,$SecureSecret
$TenantID="<tenant-Id>"
# We can then connnect to our Azure account via the use of the Service Principal
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $Credential -Tenant $TenantID
# Now go ahead and create the resource group
$ResourceGroupName ="powershell-grp"
$Location = "North Europe"
New-AzResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroupName -Location $Location
```

**Run the Pipeline :-**

[image]

**Job Succeeded :-**
The Powershell pipeline authenticated with Service Principal and ran successfully inside a Gitlab.

[image]

Resource Group created on Azure Portal :-

[image]

If you want to automate multiple Powershell Batch scripts operation. You can edit your Yaml file to run multiple jobs in multiple stages in single main branch or use different stages in different branch to release your scripts via PowerShell refer below :-

**Multiple Branch :-**

[image]

**Single Branch > Multiple Jobs and Multiple Stages :-**

**Code -**

```yaml
    variables:
     DEFAULT_RG:
       description: "Default resource group to                  deploy the resources for testing"
       value: "test-rg"
      DEFAULT_LOCATION:
    description: "Default location of the testing resource group"
    value: "northeurope"
   default:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:latest
    before_script:
    -pwsh ./myscript.ps1
   stages:
    - validate
    - deploy
    - destroy
   validate virtual network:
    stage: validate
    script:
    - pwsh ./myscript.ps2
   validate virtual machine:
    stage: validate
    script:
    - pwsh ./myscript.ps3
   deploy virtual network:
    stage: deploy
    script:
    - pwsh ./myscript.ps4 
   deploy virtual machine:
    stage: deploy
    script:
    - pwsh ./myscript.ps5
    needs:
    - job: "deploy virtual network
   destroy test environment:
    stage: destroy
    script:
      - pwsh ./myscript.ps6
```

You can import your code file directly from github, Azure repos or create a new project in the gitlab.
Once you run an entire project you can check your branch wise deployment too.
You can also schedule your pipeline to run your scripts at specific time:-

[image]

Reference :-

[Azure Infrastructure Automation with Gitlab CI - Onur Yasarlar](https://www.onuryasarlar.com/azure/azure-infrastructure-automation-with-gitlab-ci#setting-up-.gitlab-ci.yaml)

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions. Being a beginner in Gitlab, this will help a lot.